# How to connect Unity Android app with MS SQL server

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build an android application from Unity to connect with a MS SQL server database. I have found some approaches that worked on editor, mostly based on directly connecting from Unity to SQL server. However, this approach does not work when I build the android app. I only need to perform "select" (to login) and "insert" (to insert session data). Can you guys give some tips on the best way to do it? In addition, I thought maybe using a web service could be necessary, but I haven't found many examples using ASP.NET as intermediary web server.

Answer (score 1):

```
With this kind of set-up you would generally call the the unity app the "client", because it's the part of the system which the end-user uses to view and interact with the world.
```

Your client would never normally have direct access to the database. This would generally represent a significant security problem. What is more typical is that clients would talk to a dedicated multiuser server application using socket connections (for example, something like SmartFox server, or often - for MMOs - a custom written server app).

It's also the case with simpler database interactions - such as a server-side scoreboard - that your client would never access the database directly, for similar security reasons. Instead, your client (the game) would talk to specially written server-side scripts (eg, in PHP or ASP), which in turn would access the database themselves.

Therefore it's only ever server-side programs that are under your complete control which have authorisation to directly access the databases, and your clients (which are less trusted, because they're in your user's hands!) are restricted to making higher level requests via an API of your own design, which is restricted to relevant commands such as "SubmitScore", and "RetrieveScoreboard" in the case of scores, or things like "MoveToLocation", "TakeItem", "Say Message", etc for a multiplayer RPG.

This multiuser server would then deal with handling interactions in your world, and it would be responsible for interacting with the database behind the scenes to create, read, update and delete information from the DB such as user details and persistent world data.

For this reason, your Unity client need never know about the existence of such things as SQL, tables, records, etc :-) These are all things which should stay on your server, either as server scripts or within your multiuser server application.

```
public void connect(){


         string connectionString =
             "Server=servername;" +
             "Database=dbname;" +
             "User ID=userid;" +
             "Password=pass;" +
             "Integrated Security=True";

         result = new List<float> ();
         resultCas = new List<DateTime> ();

         using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
         {
             SqlCommand c; SqlDataReader da; SqlParameter param1; SqlParameter param2; SqlParameter param3; SqlParameter param4;
              conn.Open();
             c = new SqlCommand();
             c.Connection = conn;
             c.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             c.CommandText = "commandtext";
             param1 = c.Parameters.Add("@identify",SqlDbType.Int);        
             param1.Value = 1;
             param2 = c.Parameters.Add("@startTime",SqlDbType.DateTime);
             param2.Value = "2010-11-10 07:45:00.000";
             param3 = c.Parameters.Add("@endTime",SqlDbType.DateTime);
             param3.Value = "2010-11-12 10:15:00.000";
             param4 = c.Parameters.Add("@args",SqlDbType.NVarChar);
             param4.Value = "I";
             da = c.ExecuteReader();
             while (da.Read())
             {
                 resultCas.Add(da.GetDateTime(0));
                 result.Add((float)da.GetDouble(1));
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: I see. I need simple interactions: the user logs in with its id and password; answer a form, which must be inserted into the database. So, you're saying that, in my case (which I consider simple interactions), I should work on server-side scripts?

Comment: And about your script example, it should be on unity side or asp.net? I have made something similar on login (just a selection function) on unity side, but doesn't work on android.

Comment: You do not connect to MySQL from your app like this. Notice how the database login details are exposed in the app. Don't do this!

Comment: @Programmer I understand. But what approach do you recommend to use or even technologies to help me look into it? I`m thinking about asp.net or php as mentioned earlier. The database is all set, all I need is select and insert operations.

Comment: @Programmer I've seen the link you marked as duplicated, but I asked here to better clarify the options on the server side. Thank you.

Comment: asp.net or php, that's your decision. You decide what to use. As long as the MySQL code is not running on Unity like this answer then that's fine. Look into php and asp.net then see which one you find easier. Use that one.